# How to temporarily remove the un-staged changes and then recover them afterwards

Tags: git

I have some un-staged changes and I would like to temporarily discard them to start a build without them.

After the build, I would like to recover those un-staged changes, what could I achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `git stash`, but in this case just create a stash commit based only on the working directory:

```
git stash save --keep-index
```

This would not touch your stage, should you already have any files in it.  After you have finished the build and you wish to apply the stash to your working directory, use:

```
git stash apply
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**
     You can use `stash@{<revision>}` to execute the command on any desired any stash

## Stash commands

#### `git stash` (no parameters)

Stash with untracked files

```
$ git stash -u
$ git stash [save] -u
```

#### `git stash pop`

```
# Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on top
# of the current working tree stat

$ git stash pop

# Pop a specific stash    
$ git stash pop stash@{2}
```

#### `git stash list`

```
# List all stashes     
$ git stash list
```

#### `git stash drop`

```
# Drop a specific stash
$ git stash drop stash@{1}

# Drop all stashes
$ git stash clear
```

#### `git stash apply`

```
# Like pop, but **does not remove** the stash from the stash list
```

#### `git stash show`

```
# Show the changes recorded in the stash as a diff between 
# the stashed state and its original parent

$ git stash show
```

---

For example:

#### View the stash content

```
# display on the stash content
git stash show stash@{1} -u

# checkout the desired commit and choose the right action you want
git checkout -p stash@{0} -p <path to file>
```

[image]